# Unsuspected behaviour and context in php inheritance

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have encountered some verry weird behaviour in PHP. I don't know if this occurs in all other oop languages so this is bonus question - does it? Ok so as far as my knowledge tells me:

1. When you inherit something from base class you basicly copy - paste the protected and public methods in the child class and not the private.
2. You can't have access to a class private members.
3. When calling a method of concrete instance you should be calling that method in the instances context as if it is his own method of his own class, where $this points to the object that called the method ( the instance of the class ).

As far as my testing in plain PHP non of this is true and I am completly mindpucked. Can anyone explaint this weird(for me) behavior?

Here is the testing code:

```
<?php

class A {
    private function foo() {
        echo "Here are the private stuff that only A class knows about..." .     '</br>';
        echo "The class name of this function is" . __CLASS__ . '</br>';
    }
    public function test() {
        $this->foo();
    }
}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends A {
    private function foo() {
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->test();
$b = new B();
$b->test();
$c = new C();
$c->test();

$reflectionA = new ReflectionClass($a);
$reflectionB = new ReflectionClass($b);
$reflectionC = new ReflectionClass($c);

var_dump($reflectionA->getMethods());
var_dump($reflectionB->getMethods());
var_dump($reflectionC->getMethods());
var_dump($reflectionB->hasMethod('foo'));
```

Comment: so whats wrong in the above code?

Comment: For example if you copy - paste the method test in class B you get a completly different behaviour. Ok I know inheritance by definition is the tightes coupling, but I didn't expect when you are calling a method that class B inherited from class A that you call that method as if it is method of class A and not method of class B. In C we have an instance of C and we have function test with $this in it that points to class A foo and not to class C foo. This is quite disturbing for me. I need an explanation.

Comment: You stumble about the issue of "late state binding" or "early state binding". You can read about that and how it is handled or controlled in php.

Comment: (BTW: that is one reason why your explanation of OOP principles using a "copy and paste" picture is not a good one. Things simply are different.)

Comment: Well is this supposed to be some kind-a Closure? I mean clearly function foo remembers where it is created?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, B extends A and receives all its methods, not 'copy', as you said, but receives access to them, to those, which are not private. It does not have its own private `foo()`, but it has parent's test, and when you call

```
$b->test();
```

php understands, what are you searching for, checks, are there any `test()` method in B - there are not, so it tests then, are there any in A - and finds, and uses it. As A has private `foo()`, and it is called by A's method `test()` - it is also working.

As for C, situation is the same, except it has its own private method. But A's method `foo()` is looking for a method `foo()`in class A, so it works too.

Comment: Ok and let's say you have a private propery in Class A - private $secretData = 'Some top secret data';
and test in A is public function test(){echo $this->secretData;}
In the same situation we get the 3 times top secred data. I mean wasn't supposed private properties to be private? Also if we have two private properties with same name in class A and B and test() refers to that propery it will always call the A's and not as I expect the B's private property. This can couse some weird bugs I think, don't you? And it is something we should be carefull I get what happens I wan'to to know why.

Comment: Yes, it is a bit weird, I agree.
Actually I prefer python way of thinking about all those encapsulation things: "We are all adults" :) I don't expect too much from hiding properties, I expect much from people I am working with.

Comment: So is this feature only in PHP?

Comment: I don't know much languages, but in some private things can be accessed to. Not very straight way, but they can.